# ArcGIS Issue with Python wildcard in Label Expression?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, python-parser, expression

Here is my current expression:

```
def FindLabel ( [FULL_NAME] ):
fn = [FULL_NAME]
if "COUNTY ROAD" in fn:
 return  "CR " + fn[11:]
elif "% COUNTY ROAD" in fn:
 return fn[:1] + "CR" + fn[13:]
else:
 return fn
```

This is a valid expression but the line - elif "% COUNTY ROAD" in fn:
     return fn[:1] + "CR" + fn[13:] isn't working. Some county roads have a pre directional (i.e. E or W) then COUNTY ROAD XXXX. I am trying to return that pre-directional with % wildcard if it exists in the FULL_NAME field.

Is this not correct?

Comment: The % symbol is a SQL wildcard, not Python. Python doesn't have wildcards (ignoring glob and re modules).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all you want to do is replace 'COUNTRY ROAD' with 'CR'.

You can use `str.replace()` to do that.

```
def find_label(full_name):
   return full_name.replace('COUNTRY ROAD', 'CR')
```

Comment: Correct, but how would I account for "W COUNTY ROAD 3066" to label as "W CR 3066"?

Comment: Nevermind, that str.replace() covers everything. Thanks!